# Does MS use the data on Azure for internal machine learning?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api

My organization wants to use Microsoft Text Analytics API for sentiment analysis. But my employer concern is that MS will be using that data for the live training of their sentiment engine. Is this the case?

Comment: Text Analysis API doesn't offer a training option so the only way MS could use the data would be to store them and display them to their employees for analysis. Which would be a violation of GDPR and all of their certifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Microsoft Trust Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trustcenter/privacy/you-own-your-data) for your answer.

> How we manage your data
>
> With Microsoft, you are the owner of your customer data.
>
> Microsoft will use your customer data only to provide the services we
> have agreed upon, and for purposes that are compatible with providing
> those services. We do not share your data with our
> advertiser-supported services, nor do we mine it for marketing or
> advertising. If you leave the service, we take the necessary steps to
> ensure the continued ownership of your data.